# Error when I put choices in Charfield in a Serializer which is not based on Model - Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I make a serializer, which is not based on a model and one of the fields is a charfield in which I want to put a specific choices. Is that possible?

The error I get when I put the code:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices'

```
STATUS_TYPES = (
    ('', ''),
    ('male', 'male'),
    ('female', 'female')
)

class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    gender = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, choices=GENDER_TYPES)
```

Answer (score 2):

**To use choice field in Django Rest Framework use : [ChoiceField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#choicefield) or [MultipleChoiceField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#multiplechoicefield) instead of Charfield(..., choices=(...))**

In your case :

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    gender = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_TYPES)
```

Comment: Resurrecting an old thread, just to point out, neither ChoiceField nor MultipleChoiceField allow for min/max_length option that CharField allows.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this by using `SerializerMethodField`. I assume the first element in `GENDER_TYPES` tuple is the source and the second element is what you want it to be.

```
GENDER_TYPES = (
    ('', ''),
    ('male', 'male'),
    ('female', 'female')
)

class SomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    gender = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_gender(self, obj):
        return next(filter(lambda gt: gt[0] == obj['gender'], GENDER_TYPES))[1]
```